# MS Excel - How to auto count dates

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to add 10 days (date format 10/01/2014) from a column and show it on column 2 on an empty workbook automatically so my colleagues will enter just one column and the formula calculates the other column for them?

Comment: to add 10 days to a date you simple add 10.  for example if your date is in A1.  In B1 put `=A1+10` and format the cell to look like you want.

Comment: I understand. But how can make it on-demand on an empty wookbook. If I have the cell empty and someone a new entry is entered it should automatically update the second column with date +10.

Answer (score 1):

Put a date in cell A1.  Put the formula `=A1+10` in cell A2.

To automatically populate the formula for new rows, use the AutoFill feature as described in the following link:  [Fill data automatically in worksheet cells - Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Fill-data-automatically-in-worksheet-cells-74e31bdd-d993-45da-aa82-35a236c5b5db#ID0EAAEAAA=2010)

Comment: I understand. But how can make it on-demand on an empty wookbook. If I have the cell empty and someone a new entry is entered it should automatically update the second column with date +10.

Comment: Use AutoFill, see edit for details.